# how to cluster and plot sentences based on the sentence similarity?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, artificial-intelligence, dbscan

I am trying to cluster sentences based on their similarity to each other. I am generating the embedding of the sentence using ELMo (where it generates embedding for each word and I sum all of those and divide it by the no. of words).

I initially tried to fit this data with [tsne](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.TSNE.html), with the embeddings generated by ELMo (512 dimensions) I was able to form clusters, but the problem here is, in tsne the dimensions has to be reduced where it can accommodate maximum of 3 dimensions. Hence the output was not that accurate.
Then I tried with [DBSCAN](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html#sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN), where I don't see any constrain with the dimension of the input fed to it (Please correct me if I am wrong).

Now I am struck with plotting the predictions that is been done with DBSCAN. Also when I tried printing the labels predicted, all of them was '-1'.
Is there any other way I can cluster the sentences or how can I efficiently utilise the 512 dimension embedding in clustering the sentence with either tsne or dbscan?

```
def tsnescatterplot(sentences):
    arr = np.empty((0, 512), dtype='f')
    word_labels = []
    for sentence in sentences:
        wrd_vector = get_elmo_embeddings(sentence)
        print(sentence)
        word_labels.append(sentence)
        arr = np.append(arr, np.array([wrd_vector]), axis=0)
    print('Printing array')
    print(arr)

    # find tsne coords for 2 dimensions
    tsne = TSNE(n_components=2, random_state=0)
    np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
    Y = tsne.fit_transform(arr)

    x_coords = Y[:, 0]
    y_coords = Y[:, 1]
    # display scatter plot
    plt.scatter(x_coords, y_coords)

    for label, x, y in zip(word_labels, x_coords, y_coords):
        plt.annotate(label, xy=(x, y), xytext=(0, 0), textcoords='offset points')
    plt.xlim(x_coords.min() + 0.5, x_coords.max() + 0.5)
    plt.ylim(y_coords.min() + 0.5, y_coords.max() + 0.5)
    plt.show()

def dbscan_scatterplot(sentences):
    arr = np.empty((0, 512), dtype='f')
    for sentence in sentences:
        wrd_vector = get_elmo_embeddings(sentence)
        arr = np.append(arr, np.array([wrd_vector]), axis=0)
    dbscan = DBSCAN()
    np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
    Y = dbscan.fit(arr)
```

Comment: if you want to plot the sentence clusters, then you have to bring down the dimensions to 2 or 3. I dont think you have much options there.

Comment: Thanks @Prince I agree with you but is there a way I could efficiently reduce the dimensions incorporating the context of the sentence so that clustering would make more sense?

Comment: each of the dimensionality reduction algorithms you are using are inherently designed (in their own ways) to get a good jist of the data in much lower dimensions, that is what they are for. Question is - which one is best suited for your job. I suggest you try out some of them (including PCA) and check the outputs which suit you. Like tSNE does not keeps the overall shape of data but keeps the neighbours in clusters together and is best suited for visualisation, PCA whereas is better option if you want to preserve the global shape of your data.

Answer (score 2):

Choosing parameters for DBSCAN is of high importance.

It is silly of *sklearn* (and a problem seed repeatedly here) that it provides default values - because these just don't work for anything but low-dimensional toy data. Instead they should require the user to specify the value.

You *will* need to choose in particular epsilon appropriately. But it will be difficult to choose this well for high-dimensional data. You will find that the results suddenly go from all -1 (nothing clustered) to all 0 (everything connected), and choosing a good value is hard. There are some heuristics for this in literature that you need to explore.

Last but not least, *averaging word vectors* tends to produce pretty *bad results*. Because they all move towards the mean. Longer documents move closer to the mean, shorter documents remain farther outside. But that isn't what you want to have for clustering... This extra distortion may be enough to ruin any signal that you had before.

Comment: Thanks @Anony-Mousse it has explained a lot!